# Are recursive foreign keys also marked as primary keys? (In Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

1. Example: Is this recursive relationship written correctly? Would Mgr be marked as a primary key or is this code correct?:

   create table Employee (
   EMPNO number(10) not null,
   Mgr number(10),
   constraint pk_Employee primary key (EMPNO),
   constraint fk_emp_emp foreign key (Mgr) references Employee
   );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would Mgr be marked as a primary key or is this code correct?

Code is correct (table gets created), but `mgr` will **not** be part of a primary key constraint; a table can have only one primary key. If you meant to say that it'll be a composite primary key (i.e. it would have two columns), it will not either. See the result of the 2nd query - only `empno` is a primary key column.

```
SQL> create table Employee ( EMPNO number(10) not null, Mgr number(10), constraint pk_Employee primary key (EMPNO), constraint fk_emp_emp foreign key (Mgr) references Employee );

Table created.

SQL> select a.constraint_type,
  2         b.column_name
  3  from user_cons_columns b join user_constraints a on a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
  4  where a.table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';

CONSTRAINT_TYPE      COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
C                    EMPNO
P                    EMPNO          --> constraint type = P = primary key
R                    MGR

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I checked it with the following sql server and It worked fine.

```
create table Employee (EMPNO int not null, Mgr int, constraint 
pk_Employee primary key (EMPNO), constraint fk_emp_emp foreign key (Mgr) references Employee );
```

Comment: You missed the point, I believe; it is not whether code is correct itself, but whether MGR column is (or is not) a primary key column.

Comment: Would Mgr be marked as a primary key or is this code correct? I believe Mgr should not  be a primary key and marked his code, correct